# Meaning of "bringen sich … um ihren Erfolg"

Tags: meaning

In [this article](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2019-04/die-gruenen-robert-habeck-enteignung-wohnungsmarkt-union) the lead intro has these (for the English-speaker) confusing lines:

> Bringen sich die Grünen mit Äußerungen zu Enteignungen und Klimaschutz
>   gerade mal wieder um ihren Erfolg? Nein, die Empörung von Union und
>   FDP darüber ist wohlfeil.

I know what the second sentence means, but not the first. Some suggestions, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an idiom. Interestingly, the two following dictionaries give nearly identical definitions and examples:

> https://www.dwds.de/wb/bringen
>   jmdn. um sein Vermögen, seine Stellung bringen *(= den Verlust jmds. Vermögens, Stellung verschulden)*
>   *umgangssprachlich* das bringt mich noch um den Verstand *(= das macht mich verrückt)*
>
> https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bringen
>   verursachen, dass jemand, etwas verliert, einbüßt, Schaden erleidet
>   Beispiele
>   - jemanden um seine Stellung bringen
>   - das bringt mich noch um den Verstand

So the question is whether the Greens are robbing themselves of the fruits of their labour (by talking about expropriations and climate protection).

Do not confuse *bringen* with a prepositional object *um…* with the separable verb *umbringen*, which means *to kill*; although, funnily enough, *jemanden um die Ecke bringen* means *to kill* as well.

Two more examples:

> Viele Spielsüchtige bringen sich um Haus und Familie.
>
> *(in sports reporting, when a team that had been ahead at some point during the game loses in the end, through no fault but their own)*:
>   Die Mannschaft brachte sich um den verdienten Lohn.

Comment: "jemanden um etwas bringen" can be translated as "to deprive someone of something".